# How to add "reload" and IsLoading status to 2nd level Observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I feel like I'm trying to reinvent a wheel, so I better ask.

GIVEN

- that I have an `Observable<T> source`
- and `Task LoadAsync<T>(T value)` method

WHEN

- I use Select/Switch pattern to call LoadMethod when source emits

  ```cs
  observable
     .Select(value => Observable.FromAsync(cancellationToken => LoadAsync(value, cancellationToken)))
     .Switch()
     .Subscribe();
  ```

THEN

1. How do I add reload functionality?
2. How do I report IsLoading status: whether the `LoadAsync` is running
3. How to cancel `LoadAsync` when `source` completes

I want to create some reusable method, or class, that would implement answers to #1 and #2.

I have this so far: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0zPhBE

```cs
public class ReactiveLoader<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<bool> _isLoading = new(false);
    private readonly Subject<Unit> _completes = new();
    private readonly Subject<T> _reloads = new Subject<T>();
    private readonly IDisposable _subscription;

    public bool IsLoading => _isLoading.Value;
    public IObservable<bool> IsLoadingObservable => _isLoading.Skip(1).DistinctUntilChanged(); //Not nice

    public ReactiveLoader(IObservable<T> observable, Func<T, CancellationToken, Task> handler)
    {           
        _subscription = observable
            .Finally(() => //Not nice
            {
                 _completes.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            })
            .Merge(_reloads)
            .Do(_ => _isLoading.OnNext(true))
            .Select(value => Observable.FromAsync(cancellationToken => handler(value, cancellationToken)))
            .Switch()
            .Do(_ => _isLoading.OnNext(false))
            .TakeUntil(_completes) //cancels loading when observable completes
            .Subscribe();
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
         _reloads.OnNext(??); //needs last value of source
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _completes.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        _subscription.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the shortcomings/problems of the code that you have came up so far?

Comment: For example, in order to do reload, I need to remember last value somewhere. Also the Finally operator seems weird. Isn't there a better way of "TakeUntil other observable completes?"

Comment: If the source emits a new item during the loading of the previous item, the `Switch` operator will cancel the previous `LoadAsync`. Is this your intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
IObservable<bool> sequence = source.Publish(published => published
    .CombineLatest(_reloads, (x, _) => x)
    .Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(ct => LoadAsync(x, ct)).Select(_ => false).Prepend(true))
    .Switch()
    .Do(_isLoading)
    .TakeUntil(published.LastOrDefaultAsync()));
```

The `CombineLatest` operator will re-emit the latest value every time the `_reloads` emits a signal.

The `.Select(_ => false).Prepend(true)` converts the inner observable from an `IObservable<Unit>` to an `IObservable<bool>`, that emits loading-status signals.

The `TakeUntil(published.LastOrDefaultAsync())` will terminate the sequence immediately when the `source` terminates (without waiting any pending `LoadAsync` operation).

Comment: Publish operator is there to avoid multiple subsciption to source?

Comment: @Liero yeap, exactly.

Comment: Instead of `.Do(_isLoading)` I could do `_isLoading = sequence`; right?

Comment: @Liero yes, the `sequence` is essentially the same as the `_isLoading`. You may want to filter out the propagation of exceptions, or add invariably a `false` value at the end of the sequence, or both: `.Catch(Exception _ => Observable.Empty<bool>()).Append(false)`.

Comment: Why not `.Catch(Exception _ => Observable.Return(false));`?

Comment: @Liero this will append a `false` only in case of an exception, not in case of successful completion. But if the sequence completes successfully, most likely a `false` will have been emitted by the last inner sequence, so it's probably OK.

Comment: Opinionated question, but do you think this (RX) is right path of implementing requirement: async loading based on parameter with reload functionality in UI?

Comment: @Liero honestly I think that there are multiple tools that can do this job, and all of them can do it sufficiently well, so it's a mater of familiarity with the tools. Personally I would probably prefer to do it with TPL components, with which I am more familiar and comfortable.

Comment: Even if there was a requirement for something like debounceTime (resp Throttle in C#)?
Angular did a great job at standardizing RX in angular projects, so everybody is (should) be familiar with it. In Blazor, few developers are familiar with RX, so I'm not sure whether I haven't gone too far :) Plus for RX is, that is is cross platform, cross language, unlike TPL

Comment: @Liero TBH my experience with developing front-end web applications is fairly small, and so is my experience with working in teams, so I am not really qualified to offer advices on this matter. :-)