# Passing Objects between different Razor Pages in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I'm new to blazor and working on an adress Manager. Here I have a .razor page, where the user can create a new contact.

Now, to add the contact to the list of contacts (in my MainLayout.razor file), I eather need to pass the new contact to the MainLayout.razor file, or the list of contacts to my other .razor page. Any Ideas or suggestions on how i can pass objects between .razor pages?

Here is my code:

My MainLayout, which has the Manager Controller Object, which has the contact list i need to acces.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@using BlazorAdressManager.Shared.Controller
@using BlazorAdressManager.Shared.Model

<MudThemeProvider/>
<MudDialogProvider/>
<MudSnackbarProvider/>


<MudLayout>
    <MudMainContent>

        <div class="master-view-container column">
            <IgbNavbar class="navbar" master-view-scope></IgbNavbar>
            <div class="contact-pane row">
                <div class="list-pane column">
                    <p class="typography__body-1 contact-number-label">9 Kontakte</p>
                    <IgbList class="contact-list" master-view-scope>

                        @foreach (var contact in contactList){
                            <IgbListItem @onclick="@(e => Navigate("/detail-view"))" class="list-item" master-view-scope>
                                <div slot="start">
                                    <IgbAvatar Initials="LS" Shape="AvatarShape.Circle" class="avatar" master-view-scope></IgbAvatar>
                                </div>
                                <div slot="title">@contact.getName()</div>
                                <div slot="subtitle">@contact.getMail()</div>
                                <div slot="end">
                                    <span class="material-icons icon">delete</span>
                                </div>
                            </IgbListItem>
                        }
                    </IgbList>
                </div>
                <div class="view-container">
                    @Body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
    private ManagerController mc;
    private Manager manager;
    private ContactController cc;
    private List<Contact> contactList;

    private void Navigate(string path)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(path);  
    }   

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        mc = new ManagerController();
        manager = mc.getManager();
        cc = mc.getContactController();
        contactList = manager.getContactList();

        Contact dummy = new Contact();
        dummy.setName("dummy");
        dummy.setMail("ichbbineindummy@geil.org");
        cc.addContact(dummy);
    }
}
```

And here is my AddView.Razor file: Here, i create a new contact. So I eather need this specific contact object in my MainLayout.razor file, or the Specific ManagerController object in my AddView.razor file.

```
@page "/add-view"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@using BlazorAdressManager.Shared.Controller
@using BlazorAdressManager.Shared.Model

<MudThemeProvider/>
<MudDialogProvider/>
<MudSnackbarProvider/>

<div class="add-view-container row">
    <div class="edit-contact-pain column">
        <h5 class="element">Kontakt bearbeiten</h5>
        <div class="group_3 row">
            <p class="typography__body-1 text_1">Name:</p>
                <MudTextField @bind-Value="nameValue" Label="Outlined" Variant="Variant.Outlined"></MudTextField>
            <p class="typography__body-1 element">*</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            Hello my name is @nameValue
        </div>
        <div class="gender-pain row">
            <p class="typography__body-1 gender-text">Geschlecht:</p>
            <IgbRadioGroup Alignment="RadioGroupAlignment.Horizontal" class="gender-radio-buttons" add-view-scope>
                <IgbRadio LabelPosition="RadioLabelPosition.Before" class="radio" add-view-scope>Männlich</IgbRadio>
                <IgbRadio LabelPosition="RadioLabelPosition.Before" class="radio" add-view-scope>Weiblich</IgbRadio>
                <IgbRadio LabelPosition="RadioLabelPosition.Before" class="radio" add-view-scope>Divers</IgbRadio>
            </IgbRadioGroup>
        </div>
        <div class="group_3 row">
            <p class="typography__body-1 text_1">Adresse:</p>
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="TextValue" Label="Outlined" Variant="Variant.Outlined"></MudTextField>
        </div>
        <div class="email-pane row">
            <p class="typography__body-1 text_1">E-Mail:</p>
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="mailValue" Label="Outlined" Variant="Variant.Outlined"></MudTextField>
            <p class="typography__body-1 element">*</p>
            <p class="typography__body-1 error-text">Diese E-Mail ist bereits vergeben, bitte wählen Sie eine andere E-Mail Adresse</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group_3 row">
            <p class="typography__body-1 text_1">Telefonnummer:</p>
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="TextValue" Label="Outlined" Variant="Variant.Outlined"></MudTextField>
        </div>
        <div class="group_3 row">
            <p class="typography__body-1 birthday-text">Geburtsdatum:</p>
            <IgbDatePicker class="birthday-picker" add-view-scope></IgbDatePicker>
        </div>
        <div class="group row">
            <p class="typography__body-1 text">*Pflichfelder</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group_3 row">
            <IgbButton Variant="ButtonVariant.Outlined" class="button" @onclick="@createContact" add-view-scope>
                Kontakt hinzufügen
                <IgbRipple></IgbRipple>
            </IgbButton>
            <div class="group_2 row"></div>
            <IgbButton Variant="ButtonVariant.Outlined" @onclick="@(e => Navigate("/"))" class="button" add-view-scope>
                Zurück
                <IgbRipple></IgbRipple>
            </IgbButton>
        </div>
        <div class="group_1 row"></div>
        <div class="group_3 row">
            <p class="typography__body-1 confirm-text">Ein Kontakt mit diesem Namen existiert bereits. Sind Sie sich sicher das Sie diesen Kontakt hinzufügen möchten?</p>
            <IgbButton Variant="ButtonVariant.Outlined" @onclick="@(e => Navigate("/"))" class="button" add-view-scope>
                Bestätigen
                <IgbRipple></IgbRipple>
            </IgbButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string nameValue = string.Empty;
    private string mailValue = string.Empty;
    private string TextValue = string.Empty;

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Contact> DeliverContact { get; set; }

    private List<Contact> contactList;
    
    private void Navigate(string path)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(path);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        
    }

    private void createContact(){
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        newContact.setName(nameValue);
        newContact.setMail(mailValue);
    } 
    
}
```

Thanks a lot <3

Leon

Comment: See:  [ASP.NET Core Blazor state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server)

Answer (score 1):

See these two StackOverflow Questions and my answers:

[How can I trigger/refresh my main .RAZOR page from all of its sub-components within that main .RAZOR page when an API call is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558006/how-can-i-trigger-refresh-my-main-razor-page-from-all-of-its-sub-components-wit/69562295#69562295)

[Blazor Child Component Rendering and Parameter Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713133/blazor-child-component-rendering-and-parameter-changes/70721288#70721288)

#### Update based on new information in the question

Almost everything in the Blazor UI is a component.  In your case `AddView` is a sub-component of `MainLayout`.

You need a Service that manages and holds the contacts.  `AddView` adds contacts through the service.  `MainLayout` registers an handler with the Service Change event.  When a new contact is added the Change event is fired in the Service.  The `MainLayout` event handler gets called which triggers an update in `MainLayout` to update the contact display.

The two answers referred to above show you how to build the Service infrastructure.

Comment: Hi, correct me if Im wrong, but both answers use child components, and I do not. At least I dont think so (again, sorry, but Im compleetly new). I updated my initial question with my code, maybe by that, it is possible to help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TomBrady - see my revised answer.  You do have a component/child component.  Being new to Blazor, you haven't yet realised it :-).   "Pages" are just components with a route that get loaded as a sub-component of the defined layout component.  The layout is a sub-component of `Router` which is a sub-component of `App`.