# In my Blazor server app, Data binding between Razor pages is not working as expected. Data is not refreshed in the other page,when data changes

Tags: data-binding, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server app. The main layout of the pages is consisting of 1) Side Navigation screen 2) Header screen and 3) the body screen in the center of the page
In the main screen (Page1) the client has to make a machine selection from a drop-down select box. What I want is very simple: I want that the selected machine is also shown immediatly in the header part(Page2).
I have programmed a data-binding like below. But if a machine is selected , it is not shown in the header screen. Just when I manual reload the page I see the correct selected machine in the header screen. What is missing in my data binding?

Page1 (Body razor page in the "Pages" directory) Here is the data generated

```
@page "/Selection" 
<select value="@selected_Machine" class="MAE" @onchange="func_MAE">
<option value="">-- Select Machine --</option>
<option value="">-- Machine-1 --</option>
<option value="">-- Machine-2 --</option>
<option value="">-- Machine-3 --</option>    
</select>

@code {
 public static string selected_Machine { get; set; }; 
 void func_MAE(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs e)
    {          
      selected_Machine = e.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Page2 (Header razor page in the "Shared" directory) Here the data should be actualised immediatly when data changes in Page1.

```
<p>Selected Machine: @Pages.Page1.selected_Machine</p>
```

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is `StateHasChanged()` REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713133/blazor-child-component-rendering-and-parameter-changes. Your "Machine data" belongs in a service that all your components can access with an event to notify when it changes, and the components can trigger a re-render.  There's also a gist here - https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/7e7b09b0403b8b707d0ddb502e4e0c8c

Comment: @AdamVincent - calling `StateHasChanged` to make a component re-render either means: 1. You're coding a standard event handler. 2. You're in a multi-step process and want to update the UI of progress, or 3. [99.x% of the cases] Your logic/code is wrong.  Here its 3.   In Blazor code peer review top of my list would be a search for `StateHasChanged` and then ask Why?

Comment: I left it as a comment, because it's simply pointing to the next step in learning the platform. If your information is more complete, leave an answer.